# Form Post Data - Save to Cookie - Read from Cookie

Tags: javascript, forms, cookies, save, load

I have a simple html form with around 20-30 fields which has two buttons one is "Save" and the other is "Load".

I am trying to work out a way in which I can run two functions one to save all fields on the form as a cookie and the other to load all the fields back to the form from the cookie.

I have managed to save individual parameters as a cookie from the form, but I have not been able to do this in an array. Also I cannot seem to pull up each saved parameter I have tried `getcookie` but this doesn't work and I have to use `document.cookie` as `setcookie` isn't working either.

```
 document.cookie="firstname="+document.getElementById('firstname').value+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC";
 document.cookie="secondname="+document.getElementById('secondname').value+"; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2019 12:00:00 UTC";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What method are you using to set your cookie values as an array? The document.cookie method should only take strings. Here is a simple way to set and get a cookie array:

```
function setCookieArray(cname, arrayValues, exdays) {
    var expires = "";
    if (exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
      expires = ";expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    }
    var json_str = JSON.stringify(arrayValues);

    document.cookie = cname + "=" + json_str + expires + ";path=/";
}

function getCookieArray(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return JSON.parse(c.substring(name.length, c.length));
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

You can set the cookie like this:

```
setCookieArray("myTest1", ["a","b","c","d"], 3); //expires in 3 days
```

And get the cookie array like this:

```
getCookieArray("myTest1");
```

Comment: I just canot get it to work. I dont know what i am doing wrong. How do i save the post data from the form? I have tried using the getcookiearray and setcookiearray but it just keep getting undefined errors?

Comment: hmm.. Maybe the issue is with how you are collecting your form data. Can you post a snippet of your form HTML?

Comment: Hi Robert, i have managed to get the above code working correctly so i can read and also save to cookies correctly now, i was calling it incorrectly on the onclick event. I just need to figure out now how to pull the post data from the form and submit for the setcookie array.

Comment: I can access the variables by the form fields direct rather than post data

Comment: ok great that you can get the data now. At this point you have several options of how to pull the form data. Are you using a backend language like PHP? If so it would actually be better to set your cookies there. Otherwise you can either use the onSubmit attribute of the form tag or just add an onclick attribute to your submit button. Then you can just grab the values from the form and alert the user.

Comment: Hi robert, so what i have done iss instead of access post data i have the code document.forms['designer'].font_id.value ; so i am accessing the fields rather than post data but this works as the form refreshes. I can now save the cookier correctly but i cannot see how to access just the area of the array, for example  setCookieArray("savedesign", [num,fontid], 3); there i have 2 variables in the array but i am unsure how to access just the areas of the array i have tried getCookieArray("savedesign"); and getCookieArray("font_id"); etc

Comment: ddd,300,144,398,178,193,fgfg,307,227,4,2,1,300,144,398,178,193,fgfg,307,227,4,2,1,300,144,398,178,193,fgfg,307,227,4,2,1

Comment: above is one of the arrays, how can i access certain areas of the array only? Is it the way i am setting the values, ie should they be named when i am using the setcookiearray

Comment: my apologies. You should use an associative array when setting your cookie. Then when you retrieve the array you will have proper name value pairs. For instance setCookieArray("myTest1", {"field1":"field1Val", "field2":"field2Val"}, 3); and then var myValues = (getCookieArray("myTest1"). Then you can access myValues.field1

Comment: Your a diamond! Thank you. Works great now excatly as i want it. The only one small change i had to make was remove quotes from the second values as they are variables. But apart from that it now works really well.

Comment: Awesome!! Glad to hear it!